# Will a Schengen visa refusal affect my border entry to Italy on an Italian national visa?

Tags: italy, customs-and-immigration

I have an Italy national visa for six months, starting September 10, for a student exchange in Italy. My girlfriend and I also applied for a Schengen summer trip before my Italy national visa starts and we were refused, with these reasons:

- Justification for purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.
- Your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained. Dated August 10.

I will be going to Italy by September 13. Is there any possibility that the refusal can affect my entry while going through the SIS process, because my fingerprints are collected but nothing was stamped on my passport?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for anyone here to predict what might happen in this case. You and your girlfriend, although granted visas, attempted to enter Italy a month prior to your student exchange program. It may have been felt that one or both of you would not observe the terms of the visa, perhaps that your girlfriend intended to stay, or that you should have waited until your visa entry date.

> Is there any possibility that the refusal can affect my entry while going through the SIS process, because my fingerprints are collected but nothing was stamped on my passport?

Yes, could be, and the earlier refusal will be accessible to border officials. Best that can be suggested is that you be prepared, as you may have a lengthier than usual interview, and need to offer a cogent explanation of the circumstances.